# How to reply to a reference in discord python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, discord, discord.py

I am trying to make a discord bot, and I want the bot to reply to the message I replied to. In this image, I want the bot to reply to sahil goyal's message of hi, instead of replying to x1nc.

How can I do this?

[image: message screenshot]

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

On the event `on_message` you can catch the referenced message.

```py
TARGET_USER = 000000000000000000

@bot.event
async def on_message(message):
    if message.author.id == TARGET_USER and message.reference:
        # assuming you have message cache enabled
        msg_ref = message.reference.cached_message
        await msg_ref.reply("Hello")
```